# Table in table style inherit mess

Tags: html, css

So I found this really nice responsive table example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jurebajt/pen/oXYMxJ), added an option to be able to toggle hidden rows (click on the clients number), and maybe not the best solution, but I need to add a new table inside of the table. (in this hidden row)

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GqS7W/884/)

```
 <div class="wrapper">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="70px">Ver</th>
            <th width="60px">Mode</th>
            <th>Hostname</th>
            <th>Clients</th>
            <th width="120px">Etc</th>
            <th>Connect</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Ver">[X]</td>
            <td data-label="Mode">AAA</td>
            <td data-label="Hostname">Name 1</td>
            <td data-label="Clients"><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">100</a></td>
            <td data-label="Etc">aaa</td>
            <td data-label="Connect">[BUTTON]</td>
        </tr>
                  <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">

          <td colspan="3"><table align="center"  width="100%">
          <tr><td width="33%">var1</td><td width="33%">var2</td><td width="33%">var3</td></tr>
          </table></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Ver">[S]</td>
            <td data-label="Mode">AAA</td>
            <td data-label="Hostname">Name 2</td>
            <td data-label="Clients">200</td>
            <td data-label="Etc">aaa</td>
            <td data-label="Connect">[BUTTON]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My problem is that my second table inherits the style of my main table, making it completely unusable for me. (In desktop view and **also in mobile view**, you can see it if you resize the window below the width of 600px) So basically I want to have a "default" inner table, no inherits if possible. Like this (my inner table can be the same in mobile view):

```
+------------------------------------------+
| FIRST ROW, CLICK ON THE NUMBER TO TOGGLE |
+------------------------------------------+
   +------+------+------+
   | var1 | var2 | var3 |
   +------+------+------+
   | aaaa | bbbb | cccc |
   +------+------+------+
   | aaaa | bbbb | cccc |
   +------+------+------+
+------------------------------------------+
| SECOND ROW, JUST CHILLIN' HERE           |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Besides creating a mess, I wasn't really able to accomplish anything, that's why I reverted the code basically to the beginning. Maybe I need divs here, I don't know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just give the outer table a classname that you use in your css, too. So only the table with the classname gets styled: http://jsfiddle.net/GqS7W/886/

Comment: @mwoelk That's not enough.. or there are other issues. Even in your version, in desktop view the inner table has the max width of the main table's first column, and in mobile view the inner table is also still transformed.

**edit** huh, after refresh, the desktop view looks good. But the mobile view is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hi your `td`'s will need their own class names too. This will overwrite the existing attributes, I messed around with it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/GqS7W/887/

```
table td.innertd {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mess of the table as well, *but* I did manage to get something weird yet functional from it.

[<kbd>CODEPEN</kbd>](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/NRazrA?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* Nested Table */

.sub {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 2px inset grey;
  width: 100%;
}
.sub tr {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 2px;
}
.sub td {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 33%;
  text-align: left;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
.breaker {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  table tr:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  table tr:before {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  }
  table td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .sub tr {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .sub td {
    min-width: 33%;
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  .breaker {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <br/>
  <title>NESTED TABLES</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Payment</th>
        <th>Issue Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Period</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Payment">Payment #1</td>
        <td data-label="Issue Date">02/01/2015</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$2,311</td>
        <td data-label="Period">01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class='sub'>
      <td class='breaker' colspan='4'>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Bankruptcy</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Rehabilitation</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Default</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Rehabilitation</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
      </td>

      <td class='breaker' colspan='4'>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Bankruptcy</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Rehabilitation</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Default</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Status">
            <br/>Rehabilitation</td>
          <td data-label="Balance Due">
            <br/>$2,569</td>
          <td data-label="Interest">
            <br/>$590.87</td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Payment">Payment #2</td>
        <td data-label="Issue Date">03/01/2015</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$3,211</td>
        <td data-label="Period">02/01/2015 - 02/28/2015</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

View in Full Page mode and then resize the browser window.